# How to go about testing which pins to short to turn on Daly BMS?

Tags: safety, testing, bms

I have a 7S DALY BMS, but I forgot to buy the 'SOC (state of charge) display board', which has LEDs that display the state of charge, and crucially, a switch to turn on the battery itself.  The board connects to the BMS with a 7 pin connector.   For an example, see:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001339044095.html

I could order the 'SOC Display board', but it will take months to ship, and I don't actually want that functionality.  I just want a way to turn on the BMS.  I suspect that if I short two of those pins together, the BMS will turn on.  My question is, is there a safe way to try all the combinations, while protecting the BMS?

I guess, more generally, is there a safe way to approach this type of problem? I am often trying to recycle things, and I'd like to improve my skillset.

Thanks

Comment: Ask the vendor on aliexpress. We are exhausted trying to do customer support for them, and we don't want to do it anymore.

Comment: I'm sorry for pestering you. I did ask them, they said to buy the display board.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Man Without A Shed on YT (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3qyypbihtE) said, that is pins 6 and 8 int the light board connector.